# How to control multiple audio player with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I create two audio players on the same web page.

```
<audio id="player0">
<button id="play0" /><button id="forward0" />
<button id="backward0" /></audio> <audio id="player1">
<button id="play1" />
<button id="forward1" /><button id="backward1" />
</audio>
```

But when I click "play0", both of them play. I think the problem is I'm binding the `eventListener` to one `playbtn`. Can someone tell me how to unbind the `eventListener`, so I can play just one at a time?

```
var index = 0; 
var playbtn = document.getElementById("play-images-"+index);
var playbtn.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
index++;

function playPause(){
    playbtn = document.getElementById("play"+index);
    if(!audio.paused && !audio.ended){
                audio.pause();
    }else{
                audio.play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be close to what you need...

HTML

```
<audio id="player0">
<button id="play0" />
<button id="forward0" />
<button id="backward0" />
</audio>
<audio id="player1">
<button id="play1" />
<button id="forward1" /><button id="backward1" />
</audio>
```

JavaScript

```
// init page when window loads
window.addEventListener('load', initPage, false);

function initPage() {
  // add click event to play buttons
  var btnColl = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  for (var i = 0; i < btnColl.length; i++) {
    if (btnColl[i].id.indexOf('play')> -1) {
      btnColl[i].addEventListener('click', playPause, false);
    }
  }
}

function playPause(sender) {
  // get audio player based on button id
  var audioPlayer = document.getElementById(sender.srcElement.id.replace('play', 'player'));
  if(!audioPlayer.paused && !audioPlayer.ended){
    audioPlayer.pause();
  }else{
    audioPlayer.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help :)